# How do I fix Rails rejecting parameters sent from form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form here:

```
<%= form_for(portfolio) do |f| %>
  <% if portfolio.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(portfolio.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this portfolio from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% portfolio.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user, value: @user[0]['user_id']%>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.label :balance %>
    <%= f.number_field :balance %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

That form uses the hidden field to send the user information to the Portfolio controller. At that time the Portfolio create method is used

```
def create
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio.save
        format.html { redirect_to @portfolio, notice: 'Portfolio was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @portfolio }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @portfolio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And it runs the parameter test that I've defined in the controller here:

```
 def portfolio_params
      params.require(:portfolio).permit(:user, :name, :balance)
    end
```

And when I try to create a new portfolio with that form I get this error message:
User(#70102221612560) expected, got String(#46914422996540)

Here's a screenshot of the error
[Rails error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72pHO.png)

Is Rails expecting me to somehow send the current user model as a parameter? It is saying it's a mismatched type, but I am not sure where to set the "type" for the expected parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your form:

`<%= f.hidden_field :user, value: @user[0]['user_id']%>`

to:

`<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user[0]['user_id']%>`

and in your controller:

`params.require(:portfolio).permit(:user_id, :name, :balance)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the strong parameters expecting a user object. Do you have any column in database with user as attribute name.If you have a column named user in portfolio table then your code should work fine. However I am guessing if portfolio has an association with user table then portfolio must have an attribute `user_id` in its table. So use `user_id` as name instead of user and pass a integer value. Do not forget to permit the `user_id` in strong parameters as well.